# Why does kerosene need inducer?

Tags: rockets, engines

We see inducers before the main kerosene turbopump in engines such as F1 and RD180. Given the property of kerosene having extremely low vapor pressure (~0.007 bar around room temperature), is this really necessary?
[image: rd180 turbopump]
[image: F1 turbopump]

Comment: Can you label the inducer in your images?

Comment: Something to check:  at what temperature and pressure does kerosene encounter that inducer?

Comment: Even if you have 0 bar vapor pressure, you only have one bar plus gravity to push fuel in the bump, which seems to be considered insufficient in this case.

Comment: And also say what an inducer is?

Comment: That the vapor pressure of kerosene is very low is rather irrelevant. The fuel and oxidizer are injected into a rocket engine's combustion chamber, not into vacuum. Chamber pressures are typically well over 100 atmospheres, 263 atmospheres in the case of the RD180.

Comment: Are we talking about the boost pumps to prevent cavitation?

Comment: The vapor pressure is highly relevant since this is all about cavitation.  The inducer serves to prevent cavitation in the main turbopump.  Arguing that RP-1 doesn't need an inducer is equivalent to arguing that RP-1 will not cavitate in a turbopump. It may be harder to cavitate RP-1 than fluids with higher vapor pressures, but it is clearly not impossible.